# SiteMapPath not appearing

Tags: .net, asp.net, sitemap

I have added a Web.sitemap and added the siteMapNode's to it. In addition, I have placed the `asp:SiteMapPath` control on the web page but on running nothing is displayed.

Here's the code of the my SiteMapPath control:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em">
    <CurrentNodeStyle ForeColor="#333333" />
    <NodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#666666" />
    <PathSeparatorStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#1C5E55" />
    <RootNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#1C5E55" />
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

Doesn't SiteMapPath control pickup Web.sitemap automatically? or anything else if left? In case, Web.sitemap is to checked, [here it is](http://pastebin.com/dtfSbVFR).

Comment: Done-Placed in the above post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you configured XML SiteMap provider into your Web.config?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" />
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also setup the control:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" SkipLinkText="">
...
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

Comment: @Cipher: What version of .NET do you use? 2.0/3.5 or 4.0?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.0 -- Visual Studio 2010. Target Framework 3.5

Comment: Thanks abatishchev for the patience but its still not appearing :-/

Comment: @Cipher: What page are you opening for test? index.aspx, any other?

Comment: Yes, index.aspx and I also tried to open another page AboutUs.aspx which was under Home.

Comment: @Cipher: Try to create a new, empty web app and sandbox the issue there. What is the result?

Comment: Doh! Works for me too on an empty website Framework 4.0 http://i.imgur.com/Jg7nO.jpg ... What could be the issue there?:-|

Comment: @Cipher: Try to comment out other nodes in Web.config / other controls in the markup

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered this problem. Writing a very simple Website.

The problem was that pages that are not in the Web.sitemap are not included in the breadcrumbs. See first note on [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178418(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
I had listed all pages in Web.sitemap, but with the .aspx extension. For example:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Contact.aspx" title="Contact"  description="Contact information" />
```

When I visited the page in a browser, the URL got "cleaned" to `http://localhost/Contact`.
Meaning, without the .aspx extension. I don't know which module is responsible for this. When I changed the entry in Web.sitemap by removing .aspx, the breadcrumbs were showing up on the page. So, the line looks like:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Contact" title="Contact"  description="Contact information" />
```

edit: The package responsible for the URL rewriting is the FriendlyUrls Package (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls)